# iOS - Accept specific self signed certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, certificate, ssl-certificate

This might have been answered before, but I didn’t get the solution.

My requirement is I want to accept programmatically a certificate and only that particular certificate. I have only a rootca.pem file which contains only one certificate. I am using this file in my app bundle (I am working on an app similar to [LinPhone](http://www.linphone.org/)
 app).

I am using this code to upload a file on my server:-

```
- (void)uploadImageTo:(NSURL*)url image:(UIImage*)image {

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu-%f.jpg", (unsigned long)[image hash],[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];
    NSString *rawSHA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageName];

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    //now lets create the body of the post
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // Open form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Append data
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",imageName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)]];

    //  parameter username
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"h\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[rawSHA dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    //[body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:self];

}
```

I have also used these delegates method to accept the certificate, but they are not working:-

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([self shouldTrustProtectionSpace:challenge.protectionSpace])
    {
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    } else {
        [challenge.sender performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldTrustProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    // Load up the bundled certificate.
    NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert" ofType:@"der"];
    NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
    CFDataRef certDataRef = ( CFDataRef)certData;
    SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, certDataRef);

    // Establish a chain of trust anchored on our bundled certificate.
    CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&cert, 1, NULL);
    SecTrustRef serverTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust;
    SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);

    // Verify that trust.
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);

    // Clean up.
    CFRelease(certArrayRef);
    CFRelease(cert);
    CFRelease(certDataRef);

    // Did our custom trust chain evaluate successfully?
    return trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified;
}
```

I am getting this error in NSLog:-

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x1705ac940 {NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1704c8180>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9808, NSUnderlyingError=0x174455330 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “abc.example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://abc.example.com:8443/upload.php, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://abc.example.com:8443/upload.php, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
```

**Could somebody please tell me how can I accept a specific self signed certificate programmatically?**

P.S:- My knowledge about the certificates is not really well.